# Can someone tell me whats wrong with my kalanchoe?

Tags: houseplants, plant-health, plant-care

The leaves at the bottom don't grow
and other leaves easily fall off. They are too soft

[image]

Comment: Leggy plants need more sun. The soil looks like mud, whereas succulents need air and drainage for their roots. You can break off leaf clusters and plant them in fresh soil. With fresh soil, the remaining stubs will also regrow leaves.

Comment: Standard potted plant question - are there drainage holes in the pot? Please [edit] your question to clarify that.